# How to do aggregation on fixed-size count-based sliding window?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

How do I implement a sliding window aggregation (or transformation) with a fixed-size count-based window?

For e.g: If I have stream data like the following

```
input stream = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...
```

Assume that time is not relevant here. And say my aggregate function is AVERAGE and window size is fixed at 3 records (not 3 millis, 3 secs, 3 hours etc), I would like my output stream to be

```
output stream = avg(1,2,3), avg(2,3,4), avg(3,4,5), avg(4,5,6), avg(5,6,7)... = 2,3,4,5,6...
```

The Windows documented in Kafka streams work are "time-based". Even the constructor of base class Window has following signature:

```
Window(long startMs, long endMs)
```

So I was not sure if it's the right tool to do **non-time based** windowing aggregating.

---

Apache Flink supports [count-based sliding and tumbling windows](https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html). That's exactly what I need, but I'm looking for a similar feature in Kafka Streams.

Answer (score 4):

If time-ordering is no concern for you, you can implement a custom `Transformer` with attached state.

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.addStoreStore(...); // add KeyValueStore here
KStream result = builder.stream("topic").transform(...); // pass in name of your KeyValueStore, too
```

For you custom `Transformer` you can maintain a `List` per key with the list being your window -- as long as the list is smaller than you window-size you append new record to the list -- if it's exactly the size, you trigger the computation -- if it exceeds the size, you trim it and trigger the computation afterwards.

See the docs for more details: https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html (Note, that a `Processor` and a `Transformer` are basically the same thing.)

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to use Apache Storrm which is also an streaming engine, kafka can be connected as a data source to it. Storm new version provides a concept called Tumbling Window, which delivers exact number of tuple to your topology. This can easily be used to solve your problem.

For more have a look at https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_storm-component-guide/content/storm-windowing-concepts.html

Comment: It looks like tumbling windows can be based on count, but sliding window is always based on time. I wanted a sliding window based on count.

Comment: It works both way,   
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_storm-component-guide/content/impl-windowing-core-storm.html, and question says you want based on count not on time based

Comment: Yes. looks like storm supports count based sliding window . Apache Flink also supports it. Wondering why Kafka stream does not support it.